# how to create strongly typed partial view from view model in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net mvc application. I have created a **view model** and I wanted to create a strongly typed **partial view** but i'm getting error. anyone can help me?Here is my view model:

```
public class AddGISViewModel
{
    public HamyarShahr.Models.DomainModels.GIS gis { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HamyarShahr.Models.DomainModels.Companies> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

my controller: I have created a action for create new information for gis entity.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        AddGISViewModel model = new AddGISViewModel();
        CompanyRepository blcompany = new CompanyRepository();
        model.Companies = blcompany.Select().ToList();
        return View("Create", model: model);

    }
```

[image: Add view][image: Errors]

Comment: You cannot select a Data Context class (its a view model and has no data context) And note this is bad practice - a view model should not contain properties which are data models, especially when editing

Comment: The error message is obvious: you need data model class which has primary key definition (given by `KeyAttribute`). The target class `AddGISViewModel` is a view model instead of database model, which doesn't make sense on scaffolding context.

Comment: I got it. Now how can i pass view model to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding is meant to generate a code that interacts with **data models**, not view models. So you have to select a model from the data context you have specified. You may want to check out the [documentation](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6).

Comment: So how can i pass a view model to view?

Comment: Passing a view model to view is another thing. Define your view model on your Razor template as **@model AddGISViewModel** and send it to your view on controller using **return View("viewName", viewModel);**

Comment: Thank you. I was made a mistake in creating view for action, because I was selected myviewmodel class into class model field in add view window. So first I made a empty template view then I added @model AddGISModel